# How to schedule method calls in a webservice built with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, timer

I built a RESTful webservice using HttpHandler to access an MSSQL database, I need to schedule method calls that will be triggered by user actions i.e. A user schedules an event at next week at 17PM, so a method in charge of sending notifications will be fired at that time. I tried the following code using System.Threading.Timer but it didn't work

```
ServiceAPI s = new ServiceAPI();
//s.CreatePreferences(true, true, true, 3);
TimeSpan alertTime = new TimeSpan(17, 30, 00);
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeToGo = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);//alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;
if(timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
       return; // time already passed
}
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
{
       s.SendNotification(true, true, true, 10);
}, null, timeToGo, System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
```

P.S. My webservice is hosted in an IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the webservice project, you need a client that will call your webservice methods based on some predefined schedules, are you using Windows Azure? (if so there is a scheduler feature there: https://azure.microsoft.com/ro-ro/services/scheduler/).

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's hosted in a free hosting service called somee. Is there no other way to do it than to trigger it from the client side? My client side platform is on Android and I'm using Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging for regular notifications, but I need to program push notifications in the case of scheduled events, so it must be triggered from the server side, don't yo think so?